# Audio sequence issue in collection view didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios6, indexing, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Sequence of audio files in collection view cell is wrong. In first cell it plays nothing, in second cell it plays first audio file, in third cell it plays second audio file , in fourth cell it plays third audio file and when clicking on first cell again it plays fourth audio file.

Why is that. What i m doing wrong in code.

Here is my code

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


audioArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

NSString *filePath = [audioArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:audioToLoad ofType: @"mp3"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: audioFilePath];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

// custom UICollectionViewCell, hold an image and its label

Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

// make the cell's title the actual NSIndexPath value

cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section];

// load the image for this cell

NSString *imageToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", indexPath.row];

cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return cell;
}
```

why audio files from array is not loading in correct order in the collection view cells.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but will try to answer it anyway.

Usually when you're working with the collection view you specify the type of file that corresponds to the project files that you wish to show. So for example, if you were loading images you would specify the type as .jpg or .png etc. For audio it might be .aiff or .mp3 .wav etc.

Once you've done this you'd use the **%ld** which represents numbers starting from 0. that would assist in loading your files in the correct order.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html

Would give you a good starting point on collection view method alternatives - this uses the named method and applies to .jpg try chaning the code to suite for audio.